# Button tag in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I am using  tags in my webApp. They are styled with css. However, the problem is with Internet Explorer 7, which has strange paddings for the buttons. How can I remove this padding?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ty7Cg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
button.button {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: It solves it but note that in some cases this fix will make your text disappear in IE7 when scrolling the page.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes IE6 + 7 ignores padding on buttons - a known bug.  The workaround is to apply

```
width:auto; overflow:visible;
```

Comment: Worked for me ;) height:auto also helped.